# Why copy only the .csproj file and not the rest of the files in a Dockerfile?

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile

I'm new to docker and I'm trying to understand why after I set a `WORKDIR` I have to copy only the `.csproj` file, and not the rest of the files? Thanks in advance

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /helloworldconsole

COPY HelloWorld.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
```

Comment: Where did you copy this Dockerfile from? You're missing the second half of it that actual compiles the source code

Comment: My question focuses on the ```COPY``` cmd, I'm aware of the missing parts. Thanks anyways

Comment: Each COPY makes a layer. It can be used more than once

Answer (score 6):

It is for Docker build cache efficiency. From the documentation

> the *.csproj files are copied and restored as distinct layers. When the docker build command builds an image, it uses a built-in cache. If the *.csproj files haven't changed since the docker build command last ran, the dotnet restore command doesn't need to run again. Instead, the built-in cache for the corresponding dotnet restore layer is reused

Regarding if you need to copy the rest of the files - yes, you do, as also shown in the docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-dockerfile